# Key missing for translation using i18next

Tags: next.js, i18next, next-i18next

I am using next-i18next in my Next JS project to handle translations. I want to make a call to the backend when a `key` is missing to store it in the database.

I have found that there are functions for this in i18next, specifically by setting `saveMissing` and `missingKeyHandler` functions (see here: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options)

However, when adding `missingKeyHandler` to my `next-i18next.config.js` file, I get this error: "error - SerializableError: Error serializing `._nextI18Next.userConfig.missingKeyHandler` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/dashboard/assettrack".
Reason: `function` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types."

This is my next-i18next.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "en",
    locales: ["en","es","ca"]
},
localePath: path.resolve('./appdata/locales'),
localeStructure: '{{lng}}/{{ns}}',
debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
reloadOnPrerender: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
saveMissing: true,
missingKeyHandler: (lng, ns, key, fallbackValue) => {
    const message = `Missing translation key [${key}] for [${lng}/${ns}], fallbackValue: ${fallbackValue}`;
    console.warn(message);
    return { message };
}
```

}

This of course makes sense, but then the question begs, how can one add their own `missingKeyHandler` function?

I have also tried creating a custom useTranslation hook that extends the native useTranslation hook, but I have not had any success yet.

Answer (score 0):

that would be because you're returning a object instead of a value, also i wouldn't return message (because the expected translation would be replaced with the message) but the fallbackValue

```
missingKeyHandler: (lng, ns, key, fallbackValue) => {
    const message = `Missing translation key [${key}] for [${lng}/${ns}], fallbackValue: ${fallbackValue}`;
    console.warn(message);
    return fallbackValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer mate. However with your code I still get the same error message. I doesn't seem to be related to what is returned, but rather that it is a function and as such not serializable:
Error: Error serializing `._nextI18Next.userConfig.missingKeyHandler` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/auth/login".
Reason: `function` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
I am not sure why the next-i18next.config passes through getServerSideProps, but this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but i could solve it by setting the `serializeConfig` inside my `next-i18next.config.js` to `false`.

From the [docs](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next?tab=readme-ov-file#unserializable-configs):

> To fix this, you'll need to set config.serializeConfig to `false`, and
> manually pass your config into `appWithTranslation`

So, the setup is something like this:

```
// next-i18next.config.js

module.exports = {
    i18n: {
      // your i18n config
    },
    // ... other configs
    serializeConfig: false,
    saveMissing: true,
    missingKeyHandler: yourApiCallback,
}
```

```
// _app

import nextI18NextConfig from 'next-i18next.config';

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
  <Component {...pageProps} />
)

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp, nextI18NextConfig);
```

Keep in mind that with this setup i still call the `next-i18next` config inside my `next-config.js` as the [docs suggests](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next?tab=readme-ov-file#nextconfigjs).